# cypher count different permutation of connections between nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a search items graph model in neo4j.

So I have the following data types nodes: 
`Item` ,
`Key`,
and `category`

- Each `Item` has several connected `key`s
- Each `Category` has several connected `key`s

I want to do a statistic check on the graph. I want to know if I take one `key` out of each `category` - how many connected `Item`s there are for every set of keys.

So, if I had `key_A`(12)  from `category_A` and `key_B`(34) from `Category_B`, I could do:

```
START key1 = node(12), key2 = node(34)
MATCH key1 <--(item), key2<--(item)
RETURN count(item)
```

Pretty simple... But I need to run the same for every set of keys. (one key from each category)

How can I run the same question for each permutation of the keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer!

```
start cat1=node:node_auto_index(name="Category1"),cat2=node:node_auto_index(name="Category2")
MATCH (item) --> (key1)<--(cat1),
      (item)--> (key2)<--(cat2)
where (item.type="item")
with key1, key2 , collect(distinct item.name) as items    
return key1.name,key2.name, items, length(items)
```

Comment: Glad you found an answer! You could also try simplifying your pattern by joining two expressions on a common term: `MATCH (cat1)-->(key1)<--(item)-->(key2)<--(cat2)`. An alternative to the `WHERE` clause would also be to type the relationships between keys and items differently from those between keys and categories, and include relationship type in the pattern.

Comment: Thanks. It does make simplify it. Still, in my case I actually have more than 2 categories and keys, Is there a way to simplify the `MATCH` line with 3 categories?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
start cat=node:node_auto_index("name:(Category1 Category2 Category3")
MATCH (item)-->(key)<--(cat)
where (item.type="item")
with key.name as key_name, collect(distinct item.name) as items
order by key.name
with collect(key_name) as keys, reduce(a=[],i in collect(items) : a + i) as items2
return keys, items2, length(items2)
```

Probably posting an example dataset to http://console.neo4j.org

or describing it as a graph-gist (http://gist.neo4j.org) would be great.

Comment: I shared my example on http://console.neo4j.org/r/ItemSearch , with the categories : "Height, Weight, Age". Tried to run your query on it, but the 'reduce' expression cannot be evaluated. (and there is a missing ')' at the first line..)